# RegistryBasedServlet Equivalent in Selenium 4

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

With Selenium 3, I was able to create custom servlets that can be configured to be used with Hub and Node.

It was possible to extend `org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistryBasedServlet` or `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` wtih Selenium 3. But with Selenium 4, I could not find the equivalent class for `org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistryBasedServlet`.

Please suggest what should be the approach taken with Selenium 4?

```
public class CustomServlet extends RegistryBasedServlet {
    // Selenium 3 example

public CustomServlet() {
    super(null);
    init();
}

public CustomServlet(Registry registry) {
    super(registry);
    init();
}

private void init() {
}
}
```

Example Reference : https://rationaleemotions.github.io/gridopadesham/CUSTOM_SERVLETS.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlets are no longer supported in SG4. They completely reworked the concept so there is no just a hub. Hub is a sort of combination of several different components.

Some of those components can be customized and provided as the custom implementation using dedicated flags like `--node-implementation`, `--distributor-implementation`, `--events-implementation`.

You can find some relevant discussion in [Selenium github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9708).

Comment: Which SG 4 component can be used for having something similar to servlet?

Comment: I think it depends on what functionality you're missing in existing implementation